# Typescript custom interface variable declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, declaration

TypeScript novice here, and i'm currently learning the language on [TutorialsPoint here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_interfaces.htm).
I'm currently having a hard time understanding the differences between these two pieces of code.

```
interface Person{
    age: number;
}

interface Musician extends Person{
    instrument: string;
}

var drummer:Musician = {
    instrument: "drum",
    age: 28
}
```

and

```
interface Person{
    age: number;
}

interface Musician extends Person{
    instrument: string;
}

var drummer = <Musician>{}
drummer.instrument = "drum"
drummer.age = 28
```

What is the difference between the two? and is there a specific situation where it is better to use the first/second implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/lazyObjectLiteralInitialization.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They amount to the same thing in the end, but the former is preferred when possible.

In this case:

```
var drummer: Musician = {
    instrument: "drum",
    age: 28
}
```

you are declaring that `drummer` is a `Musician` by using a [type annotation](http://2ality.com/2018/04/type-notation-typescript.html#type-annotations), and assigning to it an object literal.  The compiler is happy about this because it can verify that yes, the object literal you're assigning is compatible with the `Musician` interface.  It has an string-valued `instrument` property and a numeric-valued `age` property.

Now what if we try this:

```
var drummer: Musician = {};
//  ~~~~~~~ <-- error!
// Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Musician'.
//  Property 'instrument' is missing in type '{}'.
drummer.instrument = "drum"
drummer.age = 28
```

The assignment of an empty object literal to a value declared as a `Musician` causes a compiler error.  After all, an empty object literal does not have an string-valued `instrument` property or a numeric-valued `age` property.  And you're being warned about that.  Now, *you* know that the next two lines will fix that problem, but the compiler doesn't.

So you can change it to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) instead of a type annotation:

```
var drummer = <Musician>{}; // okay
drummer.instrument = "drum"
drummer.age = 28
```

The assertion is where you tell the compiler "this object is really a `Musician`, even though right now it doesn't look like it."  You're taking on the responsibility of ensuring that `drummer` is a `Musician` and relieving the compiler of the responsibility of verifying that for you.

And since the next two lines add the required properties, everything is fine.

---

The former is preferable because you usually want the compiler to verify your types if it can.  A type assertion gives up some safety, which is fine until it isn't, like driving an automobile without a seat belt:

```
var drummer = <Musician>{}; // okay
drummer.age = 28;
// whoops, forgot the instrument, but TypeScript isn't complaining

// ... later ...
console.log(drummer.instrument.toUpperCase()); 
// no error at compile time
// but blows up at runtime
```

There are times when you have to use type assertions.  For example, when you have some kind of circular reference where you need to build the object in pieces:

```
interface MarriedPerson extends Person {
  spouse: MarriedPerson
}

var adam: MarriedPerson = {
  age: 0,
  // spouse: eve <-- can't do this before eve is defined
} as MarriedPerson;

var eve: MarriedPerson = {
  age: 0,
  spouse: adam
}

adam.spouse = eve;  // okay now
```

In the above, each `MarriedPerson` needs a reference to a `MarriedPerson`...  but there won't be one until you've created one.  So you are forced to resort to having a short period of time where one of the `MarriedPerson` objects does not have the required `spouse`.  And thus assertions are required.

Does that make sense?  Hope it helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The examples are subtly different:

- In the first, you're defining a variable with type `Musician` and then assigning an object to that variable which fits that type.
- In the second, you're defining a variable with no explicit type (which means that TypeScript will infer it), creating an empty object and then *casting* that object to type `Musicican`.

  - As an aside, the preferred syntax for casting in TypeScript is `{} as Musician` - the angle bracket syntax you're using isn't compatible with the JSX syntax extension commonly used with React applications, so it was replaced with something less ambiguous.

I would recommend the first example over the second in the vast majority of cases - an empty object doesn't really implement `Musician`, so you're effectively sidestepping the type checker there!

The one scenario in which you could make a case for using the second method would be if you have a `Musician` that starts empty and gets populated later on - in that case though, I think you'd be better off modelling that through the type definition itself by making the fields optional:

```
interface Person {
    // '?' makes a field optional 
    age?: number;
}

interface Musician extends Person {
    instrument?: string;
}

// The cast can now be replaced with a proper type
var drummer: Musician = {};
drummer.instrument = "drum";
drummer.age = 28;
```

This makes it clearer (both to you, other developers and the compiler) that there's cases where those fields will be undefined.